# added path in PYTHONPATH changes sys.path entires

Tags: python, module, python-import, enthought

I have numerous versions of packages installed.  My base, system python is `~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/`
but I also have an application ('yt') which installed its own python to
`~/Applications/yt/yt-x86_64/lib/python2.7/`

I've added the yt path so that I can import a module which it includes, when I run my system python.  The problem is, when I add the yt-path to `PYTHONPATH` it adds a ton of other directories, to higher entries in my `sys.path` so that when I try to import `numpy` (for example), I end up getting the yt-version, instead of my system version.

Is there a way to keep my `sys.path` from being modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` values are always inserted in front of the standard python library paths in `sys.path`

One potential approach around this problem is to add the `yt` path to `sys.path` yourself.

So try

```
# append to the *end* of the system path.
sys.path.append('~/Applications/yt/yt-x86_64/lib/python2.7/path/to/libs')
```

this will put the `yt` specific modules at the end of the list, and your system's `numpy` will  be found/imported first.

Comment: Other things I've added to PYTHONPATH seem to be appended to the end of sys.path --- it seems to be specifically this `yt` stuff that's changing the order around... I'm not sure.  Anyway --- your idea to add the path specifically to the libs is great, and seems to be working!  Thanks!

Comment: @zhermes - I'm not an expert on PYTHONPATH but it seems to go in the middle of sys.path, after eggs but before standard modules.